# jQuery Validation errorPlacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation

Добавил errorPlacement:, сообщения перестали показываться. Почему?
Как делается в этом плагине чтобы каждое сообщение показывалось под каждым полем которому соответствует?

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#forma").validate({
   rules: {
   field: {
   required: true,
   pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,32}$/
   }
   },
   
   messages: {
   field: {
   required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
   pattern: "ttt"
   }
   }, 
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
   });
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед `errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}` добавьте `errorElement: "div",`